# Найти совпадение по символу и показать содержимое после него

Tags: javascript

У меня есть строка, я хочу показать содержимое строки только после первого символа "="

```
let str = 'jskak=ansbamm1=s=sd='
```

Comment: Можно использовать `.indexOf()`, `.slice()` например...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть множество способов сделать это. Вот некоторые из них:

```js
let str = 'jskak=ansbamm1=s=sd=';

console.log(str.slice(str.indexOf("=") + 1)); // ansbamm1=s=sd=

console.log(str.split("=").slice(1).join("=")); // ansbamm1=s=sd=

let tmp = str.split("=");
tmp.shift();
console.log(tmp.join("=")); // ansbamm1=s=sd=

tmp = str.split("=");
tmp.splice(0, 1);
console.log(tmp.join("=")); // ansbamm1=s=sd=
```

Comment: У меня есть другой еще вопрос, может быть сможете помочь)
Можно ли в такую строку поместить переменную?

let a = 25;
let s = /a/;

Comment: Чтобы поместить переменную в строку, можно использовать обратные кавычки: `let s = \`${a}\`;` Вы об этом?

Comment: Да, это я знаю. А как быть с переменой такой строки? let s = /здесь строка/

Comment: Мне надо, чтобы это было в таком формате

Comment: Не очень понимаю. Вы хотите сделать из значения переменной `a` строку, в начале и в конце которой стоит символ `/`?

Comment: Да, я именно это хочу.

Comment: Для этого вы можете использовать конкатенацию (сложение) строк с помощью оператора `+`. При сложении строки с чем-то это что-то приводится к типу данных `string`, а затем строки складываются. Примерно вот так: `let a = 25; let s = "/" + a + "/"`;